# Get at least OpenGL 3.0 for Radeon card

Tags: opengl

I have an ATI mobility Radeon HD series 5000.

I searched for it and I found that it supports OpenGL up to version 4.1

When I updated Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 I got `OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4`
Then installed Ubuntu 12.10 from scratch and still `OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.0.2`

How can I update it or what should I do to get least OpenGL 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to install the latest driver for your video card. (search for an application called "additional drivers" in the Dash, and select the FGLRX proprietary drivers).

Comment: first thank you for your help.
I downloaded additional drivers then selected "video driver for the AMD graphics accelerator" and activate it
i donot know what to do .. but when i checked for glxinfo :
(X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Serial number of failed request:  15
  Current serial number in output stream:  16)

then what should i do now ?